# Monodevelop - pad layout and docking

Tags: monodevelop

I'm just starting to play around with MonoDevelop on my Linux Mint system.  (Version is 2.6, which is a bit old, but it's what is in the repositories).

I have two wide-screen monitors, and I've not been able to configure MonoDevelop to use my normal development layout.

What I normally do, with VS and Windows7, is to have the main window contain the source code, taking up the right half of the left monitor. I have a second window containing the error and the output views taking up the left half of the right monitor.

When I go into debug, I have the running programs window take up the left half of the right window, with a third window containing the debug views taking up the right half of the right window.

The left half of the left window is either empty, or contains a web-browser showing Stack OVerflow.

My problem with MonoDevelop is that while I can drag the pads out of the main window, I've not been able to dock them together.  I can move them to the other monitor, but when I do each is a separate window.  I can't dock them together, the way I'm used to in Visual Studio.

Is this something that MonoDevelop cannot do?  Or is it simply that I've not figured out how to?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. You can dock multiple pads as tabs of a single floating window, but you cannot dock multiple pads as different split parts of single floating window.

Comment: So how do I dock them as tabs of a floating window?

Comment: Just drop them into the floating window.

Comment: I can move pads out of the main window, into floating windows of their own. But when I try to drag one onto another, nothing happens.